# Disabling back button in browser

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I have a requirment to disable the back button while login page come.

Noted below code is not working.

```
function DisableBackButton() {
    window.history.go();
}

window.onbeforeunload = DisableBackButton;
```

For serverside also i have added some serverside code as below.

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);%>
```

Comment: a number of workarounds for this in a blog..: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/disable-back-button-browser-javascript/ 
not very nice though.

Comment: @reto that's on .Net...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
window.onload = function () { history.forward(); }; //force user to redirect
window.onunload = function() {}; // trick for some browsers like IE
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution for HTML5:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    location.hash='#no-';
    if(location.hash == '#no-') {
        location.hash='#_';
        window.onhashchange=function() {
            if(location.hash == '#no-')
                location.hash='#_';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous reasons why disabling the back button will not really work. Your best bet is to warn the user:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { return "You work will be lost."; };
```

This page does list a number of ways you could try to disable the back button, but none are guaranteed

[click this link](http://www.irt.org/script/311.htm)